# grep/awk stdin Limitations?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, stdin

I looked around, but I can't find anyone who has already answered this.

I am writing a bash script which will read 6 different `csv` files, and count how many lines in all the files together have certain tags in them.

(it's a contact list database - and there are tags for business or private email address)

Here is an example of the code I have written:

```
### First Scan - Business emails ###

bus="$(awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}{print $27}' FILE*full* | grep -c "Business")"

echo "No. of Business Accounts: $bus"

### Second Scan - Private emails ###

priv="$(awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}{print $27}' FILE*full* | grep -c "Private")"

echo "No. of Private Accounts: $priv"
```

The script returns values which seem perfectly correct. HOWEVER! I know for a fact that every line in every file HAS the tag 'business' or 'private' in the same position - and there are no empty lines but when I add the two results together, it does not equal the full number of lines... There are about 45000 missing...

Are there any limitations to the `stdin` for `grep` or `awk` - the database in full is over 2 million lines long...

Please help! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about such limitations, but for a start maybe you could try to rule out the option that your assumption is wrong, and ensure that truly all lines have one of the patterns, by using `grep` with the `-v` option (inverting the selection, so if any lines are printed then those don't contain the pattern). E.g. `"$(awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}{print $27}' FILE*full* | grep -v -e "Business" -e "Private")"`

Comment: Does `wc -l FILE*full*` give the correct count for the total? Maybe some lines have a CR instead of LF.

Comment: No there are no limitations for awk. Either there is something about your input files that you don;t understand yet (maybe spurious control chars?) or you are simply wrong about Business or Private (in that specific upper/lower case combination) appearing on every line.

Comment: Mark, yes the total records match the wc -l FILE*full*.

Comment: Ed, Thing is, I wrote the program which created the csv files in the first place - there is no way any of the Business or Private would be any different from each other - they were all created equally ;-) ,and the ctrl chars should all be exactly the same as well... Oh well.. I will find the answer soon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely is that some of those millions of lines of csv include a quoted field with a comma in it. Awk knows nothing about quotes; it will just split on commas.

If you are using Gnu awk, you can use the `FPAT` variable, which lets you specify a regular expression for the fields rather than a regular expression for the field separators. For example, this will work for many CSV files (aside from the line end issue if the csv file uses CR-LF line endings). (`-v var=value` is roughly equivalent to `BEGIN{var="value"}`, and not just in Gnu awk.)

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^",][^,]*|("[^"]*")*'
```

By the way, there's no need to use `grep` as well as `awk`. You can filter and count with awk; in fact, you can do both counts in the same scan:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^",][^,]*|("[^"]*")*' '
     $27 ~ /Business/ {++bus}
     $27 ~ /Private/  {++pri}
     END { print "No. of Business accounts", bus
           print "No. of Private accounts", pri}' FILE*full*
```

The regular expression above is quite simple, and it will not deal with "incorrect" CSV files (if you can use that word for such a loosely defined format). It matches:

```
[^",][^,]*|("[^"]*")*
  |    |  | |  |  | |
  +----+--+-+--+--+-+----- A character other than quote or comma
       |  | |  |  | |
       +--+-+--+--+-+----- Followed by any number of characters other than comma
          | |  |  | |
          +-+--+--+-+--- OR
            |  |  | |
            |  |  | +----- Any number of sequences consisting of
            |  |  |
            +--+--+--------- A quote
               |  |
               +--+--------- Any number of characters other than a quote
                  |
                  +--------- Another quote
```

So the first alternative will match unquoted fields, like `93.7` or `Private`, and the second alternative will match:

- Quoted fields, possibly including commas: `"Blood, sweat and tears"`
- Quoted fields with internal quotes as per the quote-doubling rule: `"""My goodness,"" she said"` (See section 2.7 of [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).)

It doesn't attempt to match backslash-escaped quotes, which are not part of the standard (nor are they produced by MS Excel, afaik), and it will fail completely if a quoted field erroneously includes an undoubled quote.

You can use a simple variant on the above program to view the lines which are not being parsed correctly, which might let you fix them, or adapt the regular expression, something like:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^",][^,]*|("[^"]*")*' '
     $27 !~ /Business/ && $27 !~ /Private/ {
           print "----"
           print "Error at line " NR:
           print $0
           for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%2d: |%s|\n", i, $i
     }' filename
```

Comment: @glennjackman: Are you sure that all linux distros which use Gnu awk as their awk implementation install it also as `gawk`?

Comment: Ye, I had to install gawk, but the solution seems to have worked. There are now only 1104 missing records... Thanks for the excellent answer! Would you mind explaining a bit the value of the characters you set for FPAT [^",][^,]*|("[^"]*")* ? It works, I just don't understand why... :-)

Comment: @asimovwasright. Done. Also see http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=[%5E%22%2C][%5E%2C]%2A|%28%22[%5E%22]%2A%22%29%2A

Comment: Excellent explanation and resource! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tell us what output you get:

```
awk -F',' '
$27 ~ /Business/ { bus++; next }
$27 ~ /Private/  { priv++; next }
{ other++; print "Non-Business/Private:", FILENAME, FNR, $27 }
END { print NR, bus, priv, other }
' FILE*full*
```

NR in the output above represents the total records and should equal bus + priv + other.